# Laravel Classified Ads Platform

Tags: php, database, laravel, ads, organization

I am working on a classified ads platform and i am having this doubt in my head how to organize the database and the models together with the migrations.

This is my scenario

I am having an advert that belongs to a category/subcategory and need to save separate data for a given category ... For example if i select the Car category i need to keep the mileage, horsepower, chasis etc. and if i select a Laptop i need to keep the RAM, Processor, SSD etc ...

I was thinking if it can be solved with a Polymorphic relation or i need to keep those category data in separate tables (Laptops, Cars etc)

Any ideas to help me with

Thank you

Comment: Your requirements are a bit broad. From what I read each category has a set of properties associated with it depending on what the category is. If you have it as polymorphic relationship then you do need a table for each category type since you'd have the item related to a category which is morphed by the item's type. On the other hand you can have something like a category properties table with a list of applicable properties for a category. However this is more suitable for a schemaless database such as e.g. a JSON database.

Comment: I am not keeping anything in the categories table ... all i keep there is the names of the categories ... my question is where should i save the other properties i need to keep for corresponding category if an advert is of a given type of category ...